# What's this button for in Mazda cx 5?

Tags: mazda

Just received my used cx 5 from capart and this button is missing.

What's the purpose of it and how hard is it to repair?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: [Probably this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY8zxRjOuak)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a button, but a plug to cover the [shift lock override](https://www.mazdausa.com/static/manuals/2017/cx5/contents/05300201.html).

[image]